# How to plot a categorical data with numerical

Tags: r, analytics

I have two columns from a dataframe that I would like to plot. One is b wins and losses which have been converted into binary 1s and 0s. The other is distance from stadium. However I converted the distances into categorical classes  "600km and under", "601km to 1200km"," 1201km to 1800km" etc. up to >4500km.  I did this because there are a lot of games and I am trying to see if there is a relationship between losing away from home and the distance from home.

However, I'm now stuck on how to plot it because its non-numeric argument to binary operator error.

I am in Rstudio.

## Calculating distance in kilometers between Oakland Stadium and all away games.

```
lat1 <- 37.75028
long1 <- -122.2029
lat2 <- OaklandAwayGamesM$latitude
long2 <- OaklandAwayGamesM$longitude

earth.dist <- function (long1, lat1, long2 , lat2)
{
  rad <- pi/180
  a1 <- lat1 * rad
  a2 <- long1 * rad
  b1 <- lat2 * rad
  b2 <- long2 * rad
  dlon <- b2 - a2
  dlat <- b1 - a1
  a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
```

## converted the distance into discrete values and classes.

```
OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland1[OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland>0 & OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland<= 600 ] = 
  "600km and under"
OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland1[OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland>601 
                                        & OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland<= 1200 ] = "601km to 1200km"
OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland1[OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland>1201 
                                        & OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland<= 1800 ] = "1201km to 1800km"
OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland1[OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland>1801 
                                        & OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland<= 2400 ] = "1801km to 2400km"
OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland1[OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland>2401 
                                        & OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland<= 3000 ] = "2401km to 3000km"
OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland1[OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland>3001 
                                        & 
   OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland<= 3600 ] = "3001km to 3600km"


 OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland1[OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From . _Oakland>3601 
                                        & 
   OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland<= 4200 ] = "3601km to 4200km"


 OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland1[OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland>4201 
                                        & 
   OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland<= 4500 ] = "4201km and above"
```

## the part I'm stuck at

```
 boxplot(OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland1, 
          OaklandAwayGamesM$Win1_loss0, 
         ylab = "Wins Away from Home", xlab = "Distance from Home Stadium", 
         main = "Wins Away Vs Distance", col ="blue", pch=16)

Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
 non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I just would like to be able to chart something to view away wins and the distance from home stadium.

Comment: sorry not sure if it matters but some of it got deleted when I posted.

  a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
  c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
  R <- 6378.145
  d <- R * c
  return(floor(d))
}

OaklandAwayGamesM$Distance_From_Oakland <- earth.dist(long1, lat1, long2, lat2)

Comment: What does matter is that you incorrectly used a comment to modify or augment your question. Instead use [edit] facilities. Surely you can see that the formatting is decidedly inferior in comments?

Comment: Seems like you're looking for the formula syntax to boxplot:  `boxplot(Win1_loss0 ~ Distance_From_Oakland1, data=OaklandAwayGames)`